# Lambda expressions in Scala Future

Tags: java, scala, java-8, scala-2.12

I´m using Scala 2.12.2 and Java 8. For a really bizarre situation I need to use the Scala Futures in Java, and I see that using the Lambdas in the future operator it does not work.

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Future<String> future = new Promise.DefaultPromise();
    future.map(value -> value.toUpperCase())
            .onComplete(value -> System.out.println(value));
}
```

The error message said:

```
Future cannot be applied to lambda expression
```

But after read the documentation of the scala version 2.12 http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/

I understood that from now on, lambda expressions from Java8 were compatible with Scala API.

Did I misunderstood something here?

Comment: I never tried to use Scala `Future`s from Java. But I guess it is not an API meant to be used from Java. E.g. almost every method requires an **implicit** `ExecutionContext`. Java doesn't have implicits. Java has it's own `Future`s.

Comment: Well we have a protect with Scala + Java code so we have to live with the fact that Futures from Scala will be in Java environment.

Comment: Hi Paul, DefaultPromise is an implementation detail not intended for external use (as witnessed by being both in the impl package and being package-protected). Have you considered using this: https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat

Answer (score 1):

This here works fine

```
scala.concurrent.Future<String> f = scala.concurrent.Future.successful("abc");
scala.concurrent.Future<String> f2 = f.map(s -> s.toUpperCase(), scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global());
f2.foreach(s -> {System.out.println(s); return null;}, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global());
```

Comment: Mmmmm what I'm doing wrong here?. I have IntelliJ with the SDK in my project of Scala 2.12.2 and for the JDK Java 8. There's something else that I need to configure?

Comment: I don't know. Does my code not work for you? btw. I only tested it with Java 9 and Scala 2.12.3.

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ?